# How to set up 24 hour format in MobiScroll?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

I am using latest version of [MobiScroll](http://mobiscroll.com/) datetime plugin and i need to display date in 24h format without AM/PM, so i doing it like

```
$('#datetime-start, #datetime-end').mobiscroll().datetime({
    minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
    display: 'modal',
    animate: 'pop',
    mode: 'mixed',
    // 2013-03-15 11:26:17
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
    timeWheels: 'hhii'
});
```

but there still 12h format... Is there any way to set up 24 format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your timeWheels attribute is incoreect, change it to this:

```
$('#datetime-start, #datetime-end').mobiscroll().datetime({
    minDate: new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()),
    display: 'modal',
    animate: 'pop',
    mode: 'mixed',
    // 2013-03-15 11:26:17
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    timeFormat: 'HH:ii:ss',
    timeWheels: 'HHii'
});
```

So change this:

```
timeWheels: 'hhii'
```

to this:

```
timeWheels: 'HHii'
```